# How to avoid fragment recreation when tap back button using navigation architecture actions?

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, back, recreate

I am using android studio navigation component to create some fragments and switch between them using the actions. Problem is that each time I tap Back button to go back from a Fragment2 to Fragment1, Fragment one is recreated.

I want to avoid that.

I found solutions when one don't use navigation component and simply can replace ".replace" with ".add", but can't find any information on how to do the same with navigation component.

Comment: any solutions so far?

Comment: There is a function called navigateUp(). This will navigate to the last fragment in backstack without recreating it.
Call: findNavController().navigateUp()

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a normal thing that your fragment 1 is recreated, I think you have a fragment container. And when you move from fragment 1 to fragment 2, you replace the fragment 1 with fragment 2 layout using  FragmentTransaction.commit() 
If you want to control the back button of your App, you can override the Onbackpresed method in your Mainactivity class.
what specifically you want to do when you press the back button ??

Comment: Im also facing the issue. Overriding the onBackpress is not a solution there must be something that we miss.