# Fragment Recreation causes Observer to trigger onChanged() with Androidx Navigation library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

**Issue:**

While working with `Navigation` Library, I observed when I navigate back to the previous fragment, it recreates the fragment and thus re-registering all my `Observers` which triggers `OnChanged()` again

I have a `Snackbar` which shows some error messages example if I am looking for no more data present or no Internet connection to the server:

```
deliveriesListViewModel.isMoreDataPresent.observe(this, Observer {
        if (!it) showSnackBar(getString(R.string.no_more_data))
    })
```

[Source of above code here](https://github.com/shadygoneinsane/DeliveryApp/blob/29d485d537659a46bf279f4f8e0047aa7348cc98/app/src/main/java/com/deliveryapp/ui/delivieslist/DeliveriesListFragment.kt#L121)

And on navigating back and forth, the `SnackBar` pops up every time, and also every time I change the orientation or rotate my device.

**My architecture**  has a single `Activity` with `startDestination` as my `ListFragment` in the navigation graph and a `DetailFragment` as `destination`. `SupportNavigationUp` or a simple `OnBackPressed` on `DetailFragment` returns me to my `ListFragment` and then recreates the fragment and thus re-registering all my `Observers` which triggers `OnChanged()` again and the `SnackBar` pops up when `noMoreDataPresent` `LiveData` is false

Now I tried the [solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51684125/5134647) but unfortunately, it doesn't work

I have also tried to switch my `LifecycleOwner` to my activity by that also doesn't work.
Tried moving the `ViewModelProviders.of` to `OnCreate` and `onActivityCreated` - doesn't work

Please suggest corrections or any ideas what can be done to prevent SnackBar popping up after navigation and orientation change.

**Footnotes**

I have gone through these issues:

- [Multiple LiveData Observers After Popping Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892478/multiple-livedata-observers-after-popping-fragment)
- [How to avoid fragment recreation when tap back button using navigation architecture actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266152/how-to-avoid-fragment-recreation-when-tap-back-button-using-navigation-architect)
- [Is there a way to keep fragment alive when using BottomNavigationView with new NavController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485988/is-there-a-way-to-keep-fragment-alive-when-using-bottomnavigationview-with-new-n)

[here is my complete source code](https://github.com/shadygoneinsane/DeliveryApp)

Comment: I have this problem too. could you solve it?

Comment: try https://proandroiddev.com/singleliveevent-to-help-you-work-with-livedata-and-events-5ac519989c70

Comment: I also have this problem. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://proandroiddev.com/5-common-mistakes-when-using-architecture-components-403e9899f4cb), especially item 1, might be relevant to what you're experiencing. Basically, what happens is that you may have multiple spawned Observers  every time you navigate back to your fragment, thus executing `onChanged` multiple times. Using the fragment's ***view*** lifecycle as the `LifecycleOwner` should prevent this from happening, so your code above would look like this:

```
deliveriesListViewModel.isMoreDataPresent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        if (!it) showSnackBar(getString(R.string.no_more_data))
    })
```